# video not playing in safari or chrome

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video

The video is playing fine in firefox, but chrome and safari are causing issues, I have used this exact code before on a site and it worked fine, but the video was implemented as a background to a row.

On each step on the reg form a new video tag loads in, which might be causing the issues in chrome/safari.

I have added additional .ogg file types to the tags as well as playing round with varying auto play functions, still to no effect in safari and chrome.

The videos do appear but do not play... any help would be appreciated.

Please find a hosted link below

http://www.onlyukdating.com/staging/nick/f-buddy/

the HTML code i am using is

```
                <div id="fstep_1">
    <video id="bgvid" preload="auto" muted autoplay="true"  loop >
      <source src="_img/step1.webm" type="video/webm" codecs="vp8, vorbis">
      <source src="_img/step1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       <source src="_img/step1.ogv" type="video/ogg"  codecs="theora, vorbis">
    </video>
    <p>I'm a</p>
         <select name="gender" id="dating-gender" class="required gender"> 

                                    <option value="1" selected="selected"><font color="#000">Man looking for a Woman</font></option>

                                    <option value="2"><font color="#000">Woman looking for a Man</font></option>

                                </select>


    </div>
            <div id="fstep_2">
            <video autoplay muted loop id="bgvid">
    <source src="_img/step2.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="_img/step2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
    <p>How old are you?</p>
                <div class="drop_down_container">
                    <select name="dobmonth" id="dobmonth" class="required">
                        <option value=""><font color="#000">Month</font></option>
                        <option value="1">January</option>
                        <option value="2">February</option>
                        <option value="3">March</option>
                        <option value="4">April</option>
                        <option value="5">May</option>
                        <option value="6">June</option>
                        <option value="7">July</option>
                        <option value="8">August</option>
                        <option value="9">September</option>
                        <option value="10">October</option>
                        <option value="11">November</option>
                        <option value="12">December</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="dobday" id="dobday" class="required">
                        <option value=""><font color="#000">Day</font></option>
                        <option value="1">1st</option>
                        <option value="2">2nd</option>
                        <option value="3">3rd</option>
                        <option value="4">4th</option>
                        <option value="5">5th</option>
                        <option value="6">6th</option>
                        <option value="7">7th</option>
                        <option value="8">8th</option>
                        <option value="9">9th</option>
                        <option value="10">10th</option>
                        <option value="11">11th</option>
                        <option value="12">12th</option>
                        <option value="13">13th</option>
                        <option value="14">14th</option>
                        <option value="15">15th</option>
                        <option value="16">16th</option>
                        <option value="17">17th</option>
                        <option value="18">18th</option>
                        <option value="19">19th</option>
                        <option value="20">20th</option>
                        <option value="21">21st</option>
                        <option value="22">22nd</option>
                        <option value="23">23rd</option>
                        <option value="24">24th</option>
                        <option value="25">25th</option>
                        <option value="26">26th</option>
                        <option value="27">27th</option>
                        <option value="28">28th</option>
                        <option value="29">29th</option>
                        <option value="30">30th</option>
                        <option value="31">31st</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="dobyear" id="dobyear" class="required">
                        <option value=""><font color="#000">Year</font></option>
                        <option value="1998">1998</option>
                        <option value="1997">1997</option>
                        <option value="1996">1996</option>
                        <option value="1995">1995</option>
                        <option value="1994">1994</option>
                        <option value="1993">1993</option>
                        <option value="1992">1992</option>
                        <option value="1991">1991</option>
                        <option value="1990">1990</option>
                        <option value="1989">1989</option>
                        <option value="1988">1988</option>
                        <option value="1987">1987</option>
                        <option value="1986">1986</option>
                        <option value="1985">1985</option>
                        <option value="1984">1984</option>
                        <option value="1983">1983</option>
                        <option value="1982">1982</option>
                        <option value="1981">1981</option>
                        <option value="1980">1980</option>
                        <option value="1979">1979</option>
                        <option value="1978">1978</option>
                        <option value="1977">1977</option>
                        <option value="1976">1976</option>
                        <option value="1975">1975</option>
                        <option value="1974">1974</option>
                        <option value="1973">1973</option>
                        <option value="1972">1972</option>
                        <option value="1971">1971</option>
                        <option value="1970">1970</option>
                        <option value="1969">1969</option>
                        <option value="1968">1968</option>
                        <option value="1967">1967</option>
                        <option value="1966">1966</option>
                        <option value="1965">1965</option>
                        <option value="1964">1964</option>
                        <option value="1963">1963</option>
                        <option value="1962">1962</option>
                        <option value="1961">1961</option>
                        <option value="1960">1960</option>
                        <option value="1959">1959</option>
                        <option value="1958">1958</option>
                        <option value="1957">1957</option>
                        <option value="1956">1956</option>
                        <option value="1955">1955</option>
                        <option value="1954">1954</option>
                        <option value="1953">1953</option>
                        <option value="1952">1952</option>
                        <option value="1951">1951</option>
                        <option value="1950">1950</option>
                        <option value="1949">1949</option>
                        <option value="1948">1948</option>
                        <option value="1947">1947</option>
                        <option value="1946">1946</option>
                        <option value="1945">1945</option>
                        <option value="1944">1944</option>
                        <option value="1943">1943</option>
                        <option value="1942">1942</option>
                        <option value="1941">1941</option>
                        <option value="1940">1940</option>
                        <option value="1939">1939</option>
                        <option value="1938">1938</option>
                        <option value="1937">1937</option>
                        <option value="1936">1936</option>
                        <option value="1935">1935</option>
                        <option value="1934">1934</option>
                        <option value="1933">1933</option>
                        <option value="1932">1932</option>
                        <option value="1931">1931</option>
                        <option value="1930">1930</option>
                        <option value="1929">1929</option>
                        <option value="1928">1928</option>
                        <option value="1927">1927</option>
                        <option value="1926">1926</option>
                        <option value="1925">1925</option>
                        <option value="1924">1924</option>
                        <option value="1923">1923</option>
                        <option value="1922">1922</option>
                        <option value="1921">1921</option>
                        <option value="1920">1920</option>
                        <option value="1919">1919</option>
                        <option value="1918">1918</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="fstep_3">
             <video autoplay muted loop id="bgvid">
    <source src="_img/step3.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="_img/step3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
    <p>Whats your first name</p>
                <input type="text" title="Enter your first name" placeholder="First name" name="firstname" id="dating-firstname" class="required"/>
            </div>
            <div id="fstep_4">
            <video autoplay muted loop id="bgvid">
    <source src="_img/step4.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="_img/step4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
    <p>Whats your email</p>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email address" id="email" class="required email"/>

            </div>
            <div id="fstep_5">
    <video id="bgvid" muted loop autoplay >
      <source src="_img/step5.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="_img/step5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <p>Add a password</p>
                <input type="password" id="dating-password" placeholder="Choose a password" class="multistep required valid" name="password" value=""/>
                <input type="hidden" id="custom1" name="custom1"/> <input type="hidden" id="custom2" name="custom2" value=""/> 
                <input type="hidden" id="custom3" name="custom3" value=""/>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Hi  j08691 thanks for the advice, I have now added the HTML code which is fine, however it's still not playing in safari or chrome. do you think it could be caused by the css attributes or the f-steps within the form?